# Having multiple API calls in one componentDidMount - possible?

Tags: reactjs, http, axios

I've got a rather tricky problem. Within my componentDidMount method, I have:

1.) State being set on the variable 'dog'
2.) An API call being made via axios, the response of which sets the state of another variable, 'dogName'

This is creating problems (the data I want rendered to the browser isn't rendering) - so is there a better way to write my code?

```
setData = async () => {
  const x = await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breed/hound/images");
  const y = await x.json();
  const z = await y.message;
  
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    if (i <= 9) {
      newArr.push(z[i]);
    }
   }
  return newArr;
  };

componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    loading:true
  })
  this.setData()
  .then(res =>{
    this.setState({
      loading:false,
      dog: res,
    })
  })
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/dogs')
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            dogName:res.data
          })
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

You listen on both promise resolves at the same time and then execute the `setState` with all data you got.
My tip for you is: you should look into react hooks or even react-redux to get data not directly in your component code :)

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    loading: true,
  });

  const dogPromise = this.setData();
  const dogNamePromise = axios.get('http://localhost:3000/dogs');

  Promise.all([
      dogPromise,
      dogNamePromise
  ])
    .then(([dogResponse, dogNameResponse]) => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        dog: dogResponse,
        dogName: dogNameResponse.data,
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help! I implemented your code, but was still having trouble. Interestingly enough, when I just called the '/dogs' endpoint, it worked. It just seemed to crap out when I made both calls within the componentDidMount. Here's what worked: ```componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/dogs')
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({
      dogName:res.data
    })
  })
} ```

Comment: Is there an error thrown? When you put a `console.log(this.state)` into the render function, does the "dog" part exist?
Maybe you can show your `render` function, maybe there is a minor mistake there :)